# Feign.RetryableException: Read timed out executing POST [URL]

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, hystrix, service-discovery

My feign call is getting read timeout, even after adding below property to my application.properties.

> hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false

I have two more services, which got started successfully and got registered to my eureka.

But my third (A) service is not starting due to readtime out issue. Below is the case

> A calls B (For authorization during application start up - Quartz Job)
>
> A calls C (flow ends) and application should start

I have to start B & C before i start A. This is how it is been designed and i dont know the business case for this.

After adding `hystrix timeout`, the service (A) is still throwing  `feign.RetryableException: Read timed out executing POST`.

I am not able to trouble shoot , since the request are routed through eureka services, and all services are running locally , there should not be any network latency.

My eureka configuration

> spring.application.name=Foo-service
>   eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
>   eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:9094/eureka
>   hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664262/feign-retryableexception-read-timed-out-executing-get
Please refer to the above link. It worked for me