# feign.RetryableException: Read timed out executing GET

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, connection-timeout, spring-cloud-feign

I have below architecture in my project[image]

My UI Service(Port 8080) making Feign call to Gateway Service(Port 8085).
My Get call from UI service is " http://localhost:8080/invoice-list?startDate=2018-08-05&endDate=2018-10-05 " 
Similar call from Gateway Service "http://localhost:8085/invoice-download-service/invoice-list?startDate=2018-08-05&endDate=2018-10-05"

When i make this GET call from UI service i get below error within minute

```
 is feign.RetryableException: Read timed out executing GET http://localhost:8085/invoice-download-service/invoice-list?startDate=2018-08-05&endDate=2018-10-05] with root cause

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

But when i make direct call from Gateway Server to microservice, i dont get error.

**Application.properties file of Gateway service**

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=160000000

ribbon.OkToRetryOnAllOperations=true
ribbon.ReadTimeout=5000000
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=5000000
ribbon.MaxAutoRetries=3
ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer=3


zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis= 5000000
zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis= 5000000
```

Here i have set readtimeout and connecttimeout property around 8 to 10 min, hence i am not getting error.

**Application.properties file of UI service**

```
spring.application.name=external-ui-service

server.port=8080
```

Here in UI service i dont have timeout property. I tried above properties here but not working.
Obviously this UI service is not using ribbon,zuul etc. This is just an making Feign call to gateway.

So what should i do to increase timeout in UI service?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Added below properties in UI Service's application.propeties file.

```
feign.client.config.default.connectTimeout: 160000000
feign.client.config.default.readTimeout: 160000000
```

Comment: what if one wants to throw a custom exception when the time out occurs. How does one do tgat ?

Comment: surround your get/post/delete call by try/catch and wrap the `SocketTimeoutException` in an exception of your choosing.

Comment: for me those properties take no effect

Comment: So, I was using Spring openfeign starter which expects slightly different config paths: `spring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.default.connectTimeout` and `spring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.rankings-api.readTimeout`

Answer (score 1):

This issue might also be caused by default laodbalancer implementation of Spring Cloud Gateway in case you make use of Eureka Server and run your microservices undockerized on windows. Services are running on localhost, but Eureka says to the loadbalancer of the gateway to route the request to host.docker.internal.
The links down below give a couple of solutions:

https://localcoder.org/spring-boot-cloud-eurka-windows-10-eurkea-returns-host-docker-internal-for-clien

https://dimitr.im/fix-eureka-localhost

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the `spring-cloud-starter-openfeign` dependency, you should use a slightly different properties:

```bash
spring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.default.connectTimeout=123000
spring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.default.readTimeout=123000
```

Also, instead of using a "default" client name which refers to all clients, you can specify some exact client name in configs, e.g.:
`spring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.orders-client.readTimeout`

The name `orders-client` is coming from the client's declaration:

```java
@FeignClient(
  name = "orders-client",
...
)
```

Documentation link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults